# Execute own sql function in qt

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, qt

I have my sql function that should return int

```
CREATE FUNCTION returnPriceOnPlace(@SpectacleName varchar(50), @Row int, @Place int, @Date smalldatetime)
RETURNS int 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Price int
SELECT @Price = dbo.Ticket.Price FROM  dbo.Spectacle INNER JOIN
      dbo.Poster ON dbo.Spectacle.Id_Spectacle = dbo.Poster.Id_Spectacle INNER JOIN
      dbo.Ticket ON dbo.Poster.Id_Poster = dbo.Ticket.Id_Poster INNER JOIN
      dbo.Place ON dbo.Ticket.Id_Place = dbo.Place.Id_Place
WHERE Spectacle.name = @SpectacleName AND Place.row = @Row AND Place.place = @Place AND Poster.Date = @Date
RETURN @Price
END
```

testing this function in sql like this and it works fine

```
Select dbo.returnPriceOnPlace('Hamlet',5,10,'20190124 22:00:00')
```

But how to execute this function in Qt? I try it this way but it doesn't work

```
qry->prepare("SELECT returnPriceOnPlace(?,?,?,?");
qry->addBindValue(name);
qry->addBindValue(tempRow);
qry->addBindValue(tempPlace);
qry->addBindValue(dateTime);
```

Comment: You're missing the dbo in the qry prepare

Comment: "_but it doesn't work_" How does it not work? Use `qDebug() << qry->lastError();`  to get the last error. (You're also using a parentheses in your query, not sure if it's a typo in your question or not.)

Comment: I solved the problem, the point was that I did not close the bracket in here qry->prepare("SELECT returnPriceOnPlace(?,?,?,?"); 
Such a silly mistake:D

Answer (score 0):

the point was that I did not close the bracket in here qry->prepare("SELECT returnPriceOnPlace(?,?,?,?"));